# What is "Meta"? Does Facebook own Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, meta, facebook

I'm confused because people on Stack Exchange tell me to go to "Meta" to ask a question but, correct me if I'm wrong, that means Facebook right?

I'd love it if someone can clear this up for me.

Comment: No it dosen't and we used the name a decade before they changed their name

Comment: Relevant Help Center page: [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: There is a main site and a meta site for all sites on Stack Exchange. Meta is from Greek and means discussion about the main site.

Comment: One of the oldest questions on Meta Stack Exchange was posted [in Aug **2008**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114587/241919). Facebook renamed to Meta [in Apr **2021**](https://www.forbes.com/sites/lisakim/2021/10/28/facebook-announces-new-name-meta/?sh=6a4b9c607f83).

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. actually, that was migrated to Meta (Stack Overflow) in 2011.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm surprised stackexchange allowed this. If stackexchange changed their name to facebook I don't think that would have gone over well.

Comment: The full official name is Meta [site], e.g. *Meta Stack Exchange* or *Meta Stack Overflow*, not just "Meta".

Comment: [Also related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141294/the-feedback-site/141295?noredirect=1), answer there explaining the naming.

Comment: Stack Exchange doesn't own the word "Meta". [MetaFilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetaFilter) used it earlier.

Comment: Useful signpost: There are going to be other people new to the network (or who are just unaware of the meta sites) who are going to have this same question.

Comment: @BSMP I know, that's why I've added a new section to the linked faq about the naming and the non-relation to Facebook.